# Javascript code (form not saving)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some code which used to work but for some reason it's no longer working.

It's a basic form with 2 fields, saved via PHP. Here is the code.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       var queryDate = $.url.param("mydate");
       $('#date').val(queryDate);
       //var queryDate = ('2011-05-10');

        $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("save.php", $("form").serializeArray(), function(message) {
                   //alert(message);
               window.location="view-paginated.php" 
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

THE FORM PART:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="position:relative; top:20px;">
          <label for="date" style="margin:10px 0px;">Event Date:</label>
          <input value="1/1/2011" name="date" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="date" data-theme="a" data-options='{"pickPageTheme": "a", "pickPageHighButtonTheme": "e", "setDateButtonLabel": "Add Date", "dateFormat": "dd/mm/YYYY"}'/>    

          <label for="textarea">Add an Event:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Event" data-theme="a" />

          </div>
          </form>
```

THE SAVING PART (save.php):

```
<?php

include('_includes/dbconn/dbconn.php');

$date = $_POST["date"];

$textarea = $_POST["textarea"];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_calendar (date,textarea) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($date) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($textarea) . "')";

$result = mysql_query($query,$link);

echo "Event Saved successfully!";

?>
```

Can anyone see the problem please? I cannot spot it :o/

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I've change the javascript part to:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            alert('alert here');
        });
    });
```

Problem is that it never get's there...so is the problem somwhere else?

This is strange.

Comment: did you add another form in the page?

Comment: debug it by echoing $textarea to ensure that field is being posted.

Comment: Why are you even submitting it by Ajax when all you do on success is window.location="view-paginated.php"? Why not just use the form?

Comment: I suggest `$("form").submit(function(e) {` instead

Comment: ...I would really suggest using a php-framework.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It's basically not saving anything. Also I added an alert here: $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("save.php", $("form").serializeArray(), function(message) {
                alert(message);
                window.location="view-paginated.php" 
            });
        });
    });
But the alert never comes out.

Comment: Please see question UPDATE. Thanks all.

Comment: Also tried  $("form").submit(function(e) { but nothing happened.

Comment: @Satch can you answer flexxy's question, why are you even submitting a form with ajax when your reloading the page anyway? Your doing `window.location` why not let the browser just handle the submit request?

Comment: i suspect that view-paginated.php is a different page than the one with the form on it, in that case, just use the regular form submission, and within save.php do a redirect to view-paginated.php

Answer (score 0):

try to replace these lines

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            alert('alert here');
        });
    });
```

with

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            alert('alert here');
    });
```